# How can we create a data source in wso2 micro integrator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I am new to wso2(MI) micro integrator. Just i want to know how to create a data source for db connection details. From that i can reuse data source for further development.

Someone could help me to do.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, you need to define data sources inline where ever you need them. Reusing is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, how to define data sources in inline? for my custom class mediator need to pass connection details through the datasource only. In this case how can define in inline? please help me to do